# Regex for matching initials

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for 2 regex. The first regex need to match this type of expressions: P. Parker or M. Jordan or J. Guti

And the second one is pretty much the same but without the space between name and surname: P.Parker or M.Jordan or S.Gohan

I came across with this solution but is not behaving as I expected:

```
re.sub("[A-Z].[A-z]+[a-z]", "Speaker",chain)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `r'\b[A-Z]\.\s?[A-Z][a-z]+\b'`?

Comment: Be aware that `[A-z]` matches more than just letters. Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
r'\b[A-Z]\.\s?[A-Z][a-z]+\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dGLrSL/3) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb%5BA-Z%5D%5C.%5Cs%3F%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5Cb):

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` - an uppercase letter and then 1+ lowercase letters
- `\b` - a word boundary

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/olYGSo):

```
import re
s = " P. Parker or M. Jordan or J. Guti P.Parker or M.Jordan or S.Gohan "
print(re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]\.\s?[A-Z][a-z]+\b", s))
# => ['P. Parker', 'M. Jordan', 'J. Guti', 'P.Parker', 'M.Jordan', 'S.Gohan']
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work as I need. On this sentence for example --> X. Perez - bill auctions, she's --> I need to match X.Perez. I do not understand why it does not macth anything.  Wait, I have realised I need the r letter before the quotes. It looks well. Still testing the performance but I might be the need solution

Comment: @Borja_042 [It works well](https://ideone.com/EZqUJo), `X. Perez` is extracted. Just use **my code**.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you very much and for your explanation. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import re

s = " P. Parker or M. Jordan or J. Guti P.Parker or M.Jordan or S.Gohan "
print(re.findall(r"[A-Z]+\.\s?[a-zA-Z]*", s))
```

Output

```
['P. Parker', 'M. Jordan', 'J. Guti', 'P.Parker', 'M.Jordan', 'S.Gohan']
```

The regex `[A-Z]+\.\s?[a-zA-Z]*` will match any word character followed by `.` and then will check for space only zero or one and then all word character.

Comment: This is matching `5. 123_`

Comment: This does not work for my case. For example on the sentence ---> real cheap versus PGB. Not particularly Positive ---> it matches |  PGB. Not | which I do not want.